# How to prevent user to open same url in multiple tab in same browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to restrict user to open same URL in multiple tabs in same browser. How can I do this, please suggest an option or give me an example.

I am working in Asp.net c#

Comment: Giving a software stack and/or high level software architecture would have prevented my down-vote. C# does a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

That's client behaviour which you cannot control.

However, I've tought of a quite simple workaround.

Let's assume the following url: http://my.website.com/my_url.aspx

Then in your page_load you can set a session, but if the session already exists then you close the tab, navigate to another page or something else.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["PageOpened"] != null) 
    {
        // The page is already opened in another tab.
    }
    else { Session["PageOpened"] = true; }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the session when you're navigating to any other page.

Comment: but what happen when page is refreshed..?